# Are "friends" and "Freunde" false-friends?

Tags: translation

I guess that "Freund" is better translated with "close friend" and "friend" is more our German "Bekannter".

Especially in context with twitter and other social networks one seems to get a lot more *friends* than one would call *Freunde*.

Comment: Never use the marketing language of corporations to make an observation about English -- the words don't share meaning between those two languages.

Comment: @Heath: too true. Personally I'm only sparsely using the word friend when referring to someone. Actually I only tend to use it for very close/good friends. However, I know many people who use it liberally and more like it's being used in English.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think the usage is so different that I would call them false friends. If you were to draw a line representing a continuum of friendliness, and mark the range covered by *friend* and *Freund*, they wouldn't be identical but there would be a large amount of overlap.

The Facebook usage of *friend* doesn't match that in normal English either. I've many Facebook "friends" who I would call acquaintances rather than friends.

Comment: I have discovered that a friend in need is a friend indeed.

Comment: It might also depend on the age group. I think I never heard anyone younger than 30 refer to anyone as acquaintance, I was even told this sounds old-fashioned and stiff (by someone from Australia). So this might also be an American/Australian/British thing.

Answer (score 9):

I believe it's a cultural difference.

It's probably true that the "typical" American "friend" is not as close as the German "Freund."

But on the curve, "friend" is still a higher order of magnitude than acquaintance, and Freund is higher than "Bekannter."

In "borderline" situations, however, an American might characterize someone as a "friend" that a German might characterize as a "Bekannter."

The WORDS "Friend" and "Freund" aren't "false friends." But the usages might be.

Answer (score 6):

My dictionary (paper) says that "*Friend*" is "**Freund**".

Regarding "**Bekannt**" it gives "*acquaintance*" as the first meaning (and you can see it also [here](http://www.wordreference.com/deen/bekannt) for *Bekannt*; see [here](http://www.wordreference.com/ende/Friend) for *Freund*). Plus (still in my dictionary) the second is "friend", yes, but it's signalled as *informal*.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly agree with @Tom Au. This is also a "discussion" among speakers of Romance languages like Spanish for instance: ***"amigo"*** and ***"conocido"***; which happen to be EXACT translations of *"Freund"* and "*Bekannter*", and *"friend"* and *"acquaintance"* since *"conocido"* comes from the verb *"conocer"* which is an almost exact translations of *"to know"* and *"kennen lernen"*.

---

On the other hand, since German and English are Germanic languages and as a native Romance speaker I could tell easily several pairs of words (or grammatical forms) that do not match one in Spanish, French or Italian but they do in German-English. For example (en-de-es):

> **Wie** - How - *Cómo*
>   **Wie viel** - How much - *Cuánto*
>   **Wie lang** -  How long - *Qué tan largo*

In general almost every *"Wie"* + adverb (or adjective) construction allowed in German is literally translated (I think transliterate is the verb) into English. I can only think of *"Wie später"* and *"How soon"* as a not so much of an exception.

Comment: Nice observation. *"Wie später"* does not exist in German. "*Wie spät ist es?"* translates "*what time is it?"*.

Comment: @Takkat "How soon" is "wie bald" not "wie später". "How later" does not exist in English, either.