# How do you say: "Freundschaft, Genossen!" in English?

Tags: translation, usage, german-to-english

While thinking about this question:
[Are "friends" and "Freunde" false-friends?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1034/are-friends-and-freunde-false-friends)

I realized that there is one use of "Freund" that does not indicate a lot of closeness:

How do you say: "Freundschaft, Genossen!" in English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The British trade union movement and the political left in general tend to use *brothers and sisters* instead of *comrades*.  I think the expression

> Solidarity, brothers and sisters!

would match their idiom and the original sentiment reasonably closely.

Answer (score 2):

*"Freundschaft!"* ("Friendship") is — as far as I know — a form of salutation still common among Austrian Socialists/Social Democrats.

I don't think there is an appropriate English translation. I've seen this on the Internet while doing some research:

> With socialist greetings,

Answer (score 1):

In politics there are mainly two terms to address members of the own party:

> Parteifreunde = used in more conservative parties
>
> Genossen = used in the more left-wing oriented or socialist parties (e.g. SPD, PDS)

The term in quesition would only be used in the context of a left-wing oriented or socialist party setting. Literally it would translate with

> Friendship, comrades!

but this expression seems not to be used as a socialist greeting in English.

Answer (score 1):

I'd translate it with

> Friendship, comrades!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in American left organizations, the proper greeting would be "Good day Comrades, Sisters and Brothers" or thereabout...

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Beside the fact that this old question should have been moved to another SE-site, regarding your answer content: any (written) source with examples?